# PDO, using PDO with escape to get content and echo it

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to use the following code to get results from a get variable, I used another code (listed farther down) and it worked but there is no way to escape while using it, I don't know what I have done wrong but I need help, I have just started PDO, so yes, I am an idiot :D but I want to learn.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $q    = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id";
    $query = $odb->prepare($q);
    $results = $query->execute(array(
        ":id" => $id
    ));
    if($result-> rowCount()>0) {
        foreach($result as $item) {
            echo $item['user'];
        }
    }
}
```

The code that worked but didn't have an escape:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$id."";
$result = $odb->query($query);
if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    foreach($result as $item) {
        echo  $item['user'];
    }
}
```

Thanks and PS, if it is a stupid question not that I am barely 13 and I don't think any question a 12 or 13 year old asks to do with code can be considered stupid. Please tell me what I did wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't give me what I need. Can you by any chance edit the code?

Comment: By the way, you are NOT an idiot.  Learning PDO instead of falling back on the old (and probably soon-to-be-deprecated) mysql_ functions means that you're getting ahead of the curve.  ;)  The fact that you're barely 13 is impressive.

Comment: Quick question that shouldn't make a difference, but I'll ask anyway: What is the type of the id column in the users table? Is it an integer or a string? Also, what happens if you put a space after the equals sign in id=:id? That shouldn't matter either, but I'll admit, you have me kind of stumped; it should work.

Comment: the id is an int, I have it working, the answer is given below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $q = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :id";
    $query = $odb->prepare($q);
    $query->execute(array(
        ':id' => $id
    ));

    if($query->rowCount() > 0){
        foreach($query->fetchAll() AS $item){
            echo $item['user'];
        }
    }
}
```

I did a bit of looking around and asked on phpfreaks, they told me that this would work, I tried it, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewrite your results loop (everything between and including the if { } statement) as the following:

```
while (($item = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) {
    echo $item['user'];
}
```

You really don't need the call to rowCount() unless you particularly need the number of rows before a resultset.  If there are no results, the loops will fail immediately because the first call will return FALSE and the loop will fall through without any iteration.

**EDIT (DEBUGGING STEP):**

What do you see if you use this?  I'm thinking maybe you have an extra character (a whitespace) or something in $_GET['id'] that's legal when you pass it as a literal, but not when you pass it as a parameter:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  die(var_export($id, TRUE));
}
```

Comment: `!== FALSE` is not necessary. And PDO statement is traversable, you could use `foreach`.

Comment: I know it's not strictly necessarily, but that's one of my little anal habits--I always explicitly check for the value I'm looking for because so much code I've had to repair has been broken due to bugs popping up when 0 or empty strings are returned that also evaluate to FALSE.  It never hurts, and in many cases (though agreed, not this particular one), it prevents bugs.

Comment: I changed the code, thanks but I don't know what I am doing wrong: if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $q    = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id";
  $query = $odb->prepare($q);
  $results = $query->execute(array(
   ":id" => $id
  ));
  while (($item = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) {
      echo $item['user'];
  }
  /*if($result->rowCount()>0) {
   foreach($result as $item) {
    echo $item['user'];
   }
  }*/
 }

Comment: What do you see if you insert a var_export($id); just below $id = $_GET['id']? Maybe there's a space or other character in $_GET['id'] that's legal in the literal query, but not when it's passed as a parameter? I've edited my response above so that it's formatted for you to copy-and-paste.

Comment: I found an answer and I will post it as "answering my own question" thanks for your support!

Comment: I'd still suggest using the while loop instead.  Calling rowCount, depending on the number of rows, causes unintended side effects that can cause performance issues as your database grows.  The while loop fetches each row one at a time and processes the information, which is more efficient.